# Connection slow to certain website on computer

Tags: connection, internet-connection

My PC has been really slow on this website (http://www.nexusmods.com). It takes around a minute or two to load up the front page. I have searched for this issue on google and superuser but they always state that it is an issue with their internet or the servers. I do not believe it is that, that is the issue. I have tried to connect to the server with my phone, on the same internet, and it took only 6 seconds to load up the webpage. I have no idea what might be causing this and any help would be appreciated.

Additional information:

```
Ping:
Pinging nexusmods.com [77.72.3.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 77.72.3.1: bytes=32 time=229ms TTL=44
Reply from 77.72.3.1: bytes=32 time=214ms TTL=44
Reply from 77.72.3.1: bytes=32 time=233ms TTL=44
Reply from 77.72.3.1: bytes=32 time=232ms TTL=44

Tracert:
Tracing route to nexusmods.com [77.72.3.1]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2    97 ms    20 ms    20 ms  72.235.10.2
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4    33 ms    41 ms    96 ms  hnl-edge-04.inet.qwest.net [67.129.94.229]
  5    98 ms     *       93 ms  sjp-brdr-05.inet.qwest.net [67.14.34.98]
  6    88 ms   123 ms     *     ae3.sjc12.ip4.gtt.net [173.241.130.241]
  7   157 ms     *        *     xe-3-1-1.lax21.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.106.10]
  8   103 ms   220 ms     *     pni-as3257-lax2.staminus.net [69.197.1.66]
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11   463 ms   381 ms   422 ms  77.72.0.6
 12   259 ms   247 ms   229 ms  77-72-3-1.hosted-at.kloud.co.uk [77.72.3.1]
 Trace complete.
```

Comment: Ok, first thing is to find out what is being slow - is the DNS lookup taking ages, is it the first request (e.g. index.html) or all requests?

When you are testing from your phone, is it on the same network as your PC and is it using the same DNS servers?

Is the website always slow to load?

Comment: I am unsure on how to check if its dns or not, is there any way I can check?

Comment: If you're on windows, open up command prompt and enter `nslookup /www.nexusmods.com`. Do that a few times - if the IP address (77.72.3.1 by the looks of it) comes back almost instantly after pressing enter, then you can probably rule out slow DNS.